# How exactly are three user's tags selected for the "Users" page?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

If I go to the "Users"  page and search for myself, clicking on the "all" reputation tag, I [find myself](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) displayed with the following three tags in the following order: [pca], [dimensionality-reduction], [hypothesis-testing].

However, if I go to my profile, I see [the following top tags](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28666/amoeba?tab=tags&sort=votes):

- 588 -- pca × 119
- 184 -- dimensionality-reduction × 32
- 107 -- factor-analysis × 16
- 97 -- hypothesis-testing × 27
- 95 -- r × 24,

where the first number is apparently the total score of my non-wiki answers in the tag.

So why is the Users page displaying [hypothesis-testing] instead of [factor-analysis]?

Comment: I don't know the answer yet, but I note that you have more hypothesis-testing answers than factor-analysis ones, so that may be relevant.

Comment: Indeed! I did not pay attention to that. So it might be sorting by the number of answers or perhaps by the average answer score. Strangely, I could not find an answer on meta.SE. Here is one similar question, but without a definite answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113890.

Comment: Actually the answer there does seem to tell us the answer, merely by replacing "week" by "all time" (since you're asking about the all tab) since animuson (who's an SE employee) explicitly states the criterion: "*the three tags are the tags that you've earned the most votes in during this week*", keeping in mind also the distinction between 'live' and 'cached' in that answer.

Comment: Right, but then the number of answers per tag should not matter, so I am back to my puzzlement about why hypothesis-testing instead of factor-analysis is selected as the third tag for me... I don't think live/cached nuance matters in my case, as I did not post almost any answers in the last week(s).

Comment: Yes, good point... a comment there might be a good place to express your puzzlement.

Comment: The tag score displayed in the profile is the total score of non-wiki answers; perhaps the Users page adds the questions score to that. This could potentially explain the inconsistency as I have several hypothesis-testing questions, but not a single factor-analysis one. I don't have a profile on meta.SE and am a bit reluctant to create one solely for the purpose of this comment... Might do this at some later point if no answer appears here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what is happening is they are summing all votes within the given period.  For example, in the `week` listing, the top three tags listed are the tags on which you had received the most total votes over the past week; in the `month` listing, you see the tags with the most total votes over that period, etc., up through `all`.

On the other hand, on the `tags` tab on your userpage, the tags are listed in the order of upvotes for *answers* only.  Should a user not have any upvotes for answers, the tags on their userpage are ordered by number of posts with the tag.  It may be instructive to consider @Tim, who has asked many good questions, but does not really answer questions on the site.  His [listing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?page=3&tab=reputation&filter=all) has degrees-of-freedom as the third tag (one question with 105 upvotes), but his [userpage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1005/tim?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=1) lists hypothesis-testing, time-series, mathematical-statistics as his top tags (all with no answers, but with 53, 38, and 31 questions respectively).

Comment: Thanks, gung, this sounds correct. I'm not sure that this inconsistency makes sense, but at least there is some logic behind it. I will remove the "bug" tag from my question.